# Added the category via BroadLeaf admin site but unable to view in site

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

Using Broadleaf 5.2.1-GA Edition[Licensed], please help me able the category added  via Admin Site. 
The error has occurred on Site the site module.

[image: Able to add the category via Admin Site, but error has occurred on Site the site module]

[image]

Error occurred in the Site Application.

Cause of the error

> 2017-12-28 18:45:00.638 ERROR 2804 --- [nio-8443-exec-2]
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             :
>   [THYMELEAF][https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2] Exception processing template
>   "catalog/category": An error happened during template parsing
>   (template: "class path resource
>   [themes/default-theme/templates/catalog/category.html]")
>
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened
>   during template parsing (template: "class path resource
>   [themes/default-theme/templates/catalog/category.html]")  at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
>     at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)   at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)    at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:353)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   com.broadleafcommerce.advancedoffer.site.web.filter.OfferCodeResolutionFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(OfferCodeResolutionFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.TranslationFilter.doFilterUnlessIgnored(TranslationFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableFilter.doFilter(AbstractIgnorableFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.geolocation.GeolocationFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(GeolocationFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.cms.web.URLHandlerFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(URLHandlerFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.order.security.CartStateFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(CartStateFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   com.broadleafcommerce.enterprise.workflow.site.web.PreviewCartStateFilter.doFilterInternal(PreviewCartStateFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   com.broadleafcommerce.pricelist.web.PriceListRequestFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(PriceListRequestFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   com.broadleafcommerce.account.site.web.AccountRequestFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(AccountRequestFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.site.security.CustomerStateFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(CustomerStateFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.device.BroadleafDeviceResolverRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(BroadleafDeviceResolverRequestFilter.java:67)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.BroadleafRequestFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(BroadleafRequestFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.site.security.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilter(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.security.handler.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.BroadleafRequestFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(BroadleafRequestFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.site.common.web.filter.EstablishSessionFilter.doFilterUnlessIgnored(EstablishSessionFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableFilter.doFilter(AbstractIgnorableFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.BroadleafRequestFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(BroadleafRequestFilter.java:82)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.IgnorableOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(IgnorableOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.SecurityBasedIgnoreFilter.doFilter(SecurityBasedIgnoreFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL
>   expression: "#seo.getCategoryTitlePattern()" (template:
>   "catalog/category" - line 4, col 16)  at
>   org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)  at
>   org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)  at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
>     ... 169 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
>   evaluating SpringEL expression: "#seo.getCategoryTitlePattern()"
>   (template: "catalog/category" - line 4, col 16)   at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:165)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionPreprocessor.preprocess(StandardExpressionPreprocessor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:120)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:62)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:44)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardUtextTagProcessor.doProcess(StandardUtextTagProcessor.java:71)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
>     at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)   at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
>     at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)   at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
>     at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)   at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)    at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.GatheringModelProcessable.process(GatheringModelProcessable.java:78)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164)
>     at
>   org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169)
>     at
>   org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412)
>     at
>   org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473)
>     at
>   org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201)
>     at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725)   at
>   org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)  ...
>   171 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:
>   Method call: Method getCategoryTitlePattern() cannot be found on
>   org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.expression.SeoVariableExpression type
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:211)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:347)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:324)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263)
>     ... 205 common frames omitted

Comment: The error occured on category creation or only in the category view?

Comment: The category creation was fine, but the error occurred in category view, please help let me know if any more details required.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bug is that variable expression method, `#seo.getCategoryTitlePattern()`, does not exist any longer. If you look at `SeoVariableExpression` the proper method is to use `#seo.getMetaProperties(category).get('title')`. A better option would be to do something like this in a generic `seoMetaProperties.html` template to render any meta properties for the page:

```
<th:block th:each="metaProperty : ${metaProperties}" th:with="key=${metaProperty.key}, value=${metaProperty.value}">
    <th:block th:if="${value != null}">
        <title th:if="${key == 'title'} and ${#strings.contains(value,'#seoElement')}" th:utext="${__${value}__}"></title>
        <title th:if="${key == 'title'} and not ${#strings.contains(value,'#seoElement')}" th:utext="${value}"></title>

        <link th:if="${key == 'canonicalUrl'}" rel="canonical" th:attr="href=${value}"/>

        <meta th:if="${key == 'metaDescription'} and ${#strings.contains(value,'#seoElement')}" name="description" th:attr="content=${__${value}__}"/>
        <meta th:if="${key == 'metaDescription'} and not ${#strings.contains(value,'#seoElement')}" name="description" th:attr="content=${value}"/>

        <th:block th:if="${#strings.startsWith(key, 'og:')}">
            <meta th:if="${#strings.contains(value,'#seoElement')}" th:attr="property=${key}, content=${__${value}__}"/>
            <meta th:unless="${#strings.contains(value,'#seoElement')}" th:attr="property=${key}, content=${value}"/>
        </th:block>

        <th:block th:if="${#strings.startsWith(key, 'twitter:')}">
            <meta th:if="${#strings.contains(value,'#seoElement')}" th:attr="name=${key}, content=${__${value}__}"/>
            <meta th:unless="${#strings.contains(value,'#seoElement')}" th:attr="name=${key}, content=${value}"/>
        </th:block>
    </th:block>
</th:block>
```

This can be included in your `category.html` file like so:

```
<th:block th:include="seo/partials/seoMetaProperties" th:with="metaProperties=${#seo.getMetaProperties(category)}" />
```